# error appear when installing IBM Cloud CLI "'iex' is not recognized as an internal or external command..."

Tags: powershell, cmd, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to install IBM Cloud CLI but there is a problem faced me when I do this.
I added the Path to environment variables but it didn't work too !
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the `iex` (shorthand for `Invoke-Expression`) command is a Powershell command, but it is entered to Command prompt. The latter is the old command shell that dates back to the MS-DOS days of the 80's.

One can tell the difference from the fact that the window title bar says `Command Prompt`, not `Powershell`. Often - not always! - a Powershell session has blue background and command has black.

To run Powershell commands, start a Powershell session either by typing `powershell` and pressing enter into a command session, or by opening Windows Start menu and typing powershell (followed by enter).